# Restaurant Program Tutorial

Tags: java, android

I was continuing work on my Android tutorial that my teacher gave to me. The idea of the program is to enter in a restaurant name, address and type of restaurant and create an interface that shows this.

I believe I copied the code exactly. However, I get an error:

```
"The method getType() is undefined for the type Restaurant".
```

I have no idea what that means and how to fix it.

The suggestion Eclipse gave me was to "Create method getType() in type restaurant" but when I do it I get a null pointer exception when running my program, entering the details of my restaurant and saving them.

So my questions are:

- What does the error mean?
- How do I fix it?

Below is my main class Lunchlist.java:

```
@SuppressLint({ "ParserError", "ParserError" }) 
public class LunchList extends Activity {
    List<Restaurant> model=new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> adapter=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lunch_list);

        Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.restaurants);

        adapter=new RestaurantAdapter();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

   private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Restaurant r=new Restaurant();
            EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText address=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);


            r.setName(name.getText().toString());
            r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());

            RadioGroup types=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.types);

            switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
            case R.id.sit_down:
                r.setType("sit_down");
                break;
            case R.id.take_out:
                r.setType("take_out");
                break;
            case R.id.delivery:
                r.setType("delivery");
                break;

            }
            adapter.add(r);
        }
        };

        class RestaurantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {
            RestaurantAdapter(){
                super(LunchList.this,R.layout.row,model);
            }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View row=convertView;
            RestaurantHolder holder=null;

            if (row==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

                row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                holder=new RestaurantHolder(row);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{
                holder=(RestaurantHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(model.get(position));
            return(row);
        }
        }

        static class RestaurantHolder {
            private TextView name=null;
            private TextView address=null;
            private ImageView icon=null;
            private View row=null;

            RestaurantHolder(View row){
                this.row=row;

                name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
                address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
                icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            }

            void populateFrom(Restaurant r){
                name.setText(r.getName());
                address.setText(r.getAddress());

            if (r.getType().equals("sit_down")){
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sitdown);
            }
            else if (r.getType().equals("takeout")){
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.takeout);  
            }
            else{
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delivery);
            }

        }
}
}
```

This class is Restaurant.java:

```
public class Restaurant {
private String name="";
private String address="";
private Object type;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public void setType(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public String toString(){
    return(getName());
}






}
```

Comment: I sincerely hope that the instructor gave you the book that contains these tutorials, which explains how to implement them.

Comment: He did. It's just the book doesn't say what to do if this error occurs. Also, my teacher is new to android as well which doesn't help. Pretty much Stackoverflow has been teaching me android :)

Comment: "It's just the book doesn't say what to do if this error occurs" -- the book tells you *step by step* how to implement this app, sometimes includes full source listings of the results for the intermediate steps, and has pointers to [a GitHub repository with all the answers to all of the tutorials](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your Restaurant class

```
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the first part of your quest, based on the code you've given us, you definitely need to implement the `getType()` method in the `Restaurant` class.

With respect to the `NullPointerException`, that will likely be because your `getType` implementation returns the value for `type` which may not be initialised (and indeed, can't be set given that your `setType` implementation has no logic). You will need to do something like:

```
public void setType(String string) {
    this.type = string;
}
```

You may also want to do some null checking of the returned `type` value in your `LunchList` usage of `getType`. Depends on how you use it.

Comment: Your code solution didn't work but your explanation was helpful. I'd give you an upvote if I had the reputation.

Comment: No worries. Was more an addition to Ahmad's answer now that I look at it. Hope it helped :)