# Android: What’s the best way to implement the BaseAdapter if item content in ListView is dynamic?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In most case, we need to implement the BaseAdapter’s getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount() for dynamic item content of the listview, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277164/complex-example-of-listview-getitemviewtype) says. But I think this solution is only suitable for finite number and knowing beforehand, such as listview item with sending layout and receving layout.

What about the case that the listview with its item content impossible knowing beforehand?
For example, I need to show a contact list from server, the contact list size is about several thousand. For each item, I need to show, for example, the hobby “list”. It is a small range of 0 to tens of string. So in this case:

1. The item types is relatively bigger than normal case using “getItemViewType”
2. Though each item may be different, but similar to a certain degree: the item content is different in the number of views, but common in view type. Item A is different from item B only because it have more TextViews.

[image]

For each time in the getView, the convertview is hard to simply reuse because they are different, but if we create new TextView and added to the convertView, it will impact the scrolling of the listview. I don't think it's appropriate such way. What should i do in such case?

Comment: just treat your view as an empty RelativeLayout filled with child views in getView(),  so how many different views do you have?  the answer is: one

Comment: hmm, if you really want to reuse the views I dont see any other solution that making a "superview" which contains the max number of textviews, with them being visibility="gone" and toggling visibility depending on how many you actually have

Comment: Im not sure if that would be more efficient than to simply inflating the views per case though

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot easily change the number of item view types on the fly.  The `getViewTypeCount()` method is only invoked when the adapter is set on the `ListView`.  That means, were you to dynamically change it, then you would have to call `setAdapter()` again.  This is a huge performance hit as the `ListView` will toss out all the recycled views and re-generate everything from scratch again.

Honestly, it looks like you should be using an `ExpandableListView` instead.  It allows you to displays lists of items under groups.  The only difference is the groups are placed on top of the list.  So where you have A, B, C, D on the left side in your picture...in the `ExpandableListView` it'll sit on top.

The `ExpandableListView` can easily handle your situation where a given grouping could have any variable number of items within it.  You mentioned needing to store a contact list. I'd suggest taking a look at a [RolodexArrayAdapter](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) for use with the `ExpandableListView`. It may be of help.

Comment: For this case, changing the style to make A, B on top is ok. But the UE design special UI effect, such as all left side (A, B, C, D column) have line through, then as you said,the ExpandableListView seems unable handling this......

Comment: I hear ya.  May need to give up he UE special effect then.  Either that or use the ListView and take the performance hit of constantly removing/adding new views to dynamically adjust for the variable amount of data in each column letter.  Considering you have thousands of contacts to display...the ListView option probably won't work well.