# Android different layouts for each row?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to create a ListView to show different type of layouts from its rows.
I found some solutions in this site, but I couldn't apply them to my code.

Is there anyone who can help me?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder=null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
    // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
    if (row == null) {

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(row);

        row.setTag(holder);
        Log.d("App", "Creating a new row");

        switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM1:
                    //inflate layout of type1
                    row = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.scientist_1, parent, false);
                    break;

                case TYPE_ITEM2:
                    //inflate layout of type2
                    row = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.scientist_1, parent, false);
                    break;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
            Log.d("App","Recycling stuff");
        }
        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        holder.myImages.setImageResource(images[position]);
        holder.myNames.setText(nameArray[position]);
        holder.myDescriptions.setText(descriptionArray[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since both your row-types are inflating the same layout, they're going to look the same. One of your `inflate()` invocations needs to be changed.

Comment: Actually I wrote to try normally I have lots of layouts. When I run the app, app suddenly crushes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex example of ListView getItemViewType()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277164/complex-example-of-listview-getitemviewtype)

Comment: Let us know if the answer in last comment explain you how to do it or if you need something different (in that case I can delete last comment).

Comment: If the app crashes, include the stacktrace.

Comment: Actually I couldn't do "public int getItemViewType(int position){}" method

Comment: public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
                                                                      // i don't know what to do here

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to to inflate different layouts, you need to override getItemViewType and getItemViewTypeCount

```
@Override
public int getItemViewTypeCount(){
return 2; //assuming two layouts
}

@Overridge
public int getItemViewType(int position){
// custom logic determining which view type it is
// to be called somewhere in your getview method
}
```

Comment: What do I need to write in the "getItemTypeCount(){}"   I understood that (getViewTypeCount() :  Returns the count of different type of views.) how can I use getItemTypeCount in my Java file as indicated above

Comment: whatever logic you are differentiating views by. why do you need separate views? how do you tell them apart?

Comment: I have a listview that includes 21 rows and each row has different layouts.

Comment: then listview is probably not the best tool for the job. if you can't recycle layouts it's kind of pointless and you might be better off with a linearlayout inside a scrollview

Comment: You advise me to do it with recyclerview ?

Comment: no absolutely not. if you have 21 different layouts, then you have no recycling. so you can probably just use a scrollview and a vertical linearlayout.

Comment: Yes in my XML files l have just used scroll view and vertical linearlayout