# Android ListView Won't Scroll on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, listview

Has anyone had difficulties with the scrolling of a list view becoming unresponsive, possibly due to low memory, on older devices such as the Kindle Fire HD 7 KFTT?

If so, what ways could you combat that? I am already using the ViewHolder pattern.

```
public class StaffAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter, Filterable {

List<StaffItem> items;
List<StaffItem> itemList;
private final Context context;
Typeface face1;
Typeface face;
ValueFilter valueFilter;
String headerText;

public StaffAdapter(Context context, List<StaffItem> items1) {
    this.itemList = items1;
    items=items1;
    this.context = context;
    face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return itemList.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int id) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView==null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item2, null);
        holder.itemTitle1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        holder.itemTitle5 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.itemTitle.setTypeface(face);
        holder.itemTitle1.setTypeface(face1);
    } else{
        holder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    StaffItem item = itemList.get(position);
    holder.itemTitle.setText(item.getName());
    holder.itemTitle1.setText(item.getAffiliation());

    if (item.getDepartment()) {
        holder.itemTitle5.setImageResource(R.drawable.dccopy);
    } else {
        holder.itemTitle5.setImageResource(R.drawable.staffbackground);
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HeaderViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.stafflistviewtextheader, null);
        holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        if (face1!=null)
            holder.itemTitle.setTypeface(face1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
 //set header text as first char in name
    headerText = itemList.get(position).getStafDepartment();
    holder.itemTitle.setText(headerText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public long getHeaderId(int i) {
    return itemList.get(i).getStafDepartment().subSequence(0,3).charAt(2);
}


class HeaderViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
    TextView itemTitle1;
    ImageView itemTitle5;
}}
```

Comment: Usually unresponsive scrolling is due to doing too much work on your adapter. I would recommend posting your code

Comment: Ok sorry, also unresponsive touch

Comment: Posted my adapter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to your Adapter calling setImageResource(). This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause issues.

You need to implement a bitmap cache-hash list that you can reference to reduce the number of calls to setImageResource. This will store bitmaps directly in memory and reduce the reading/decoding efforts.

I experienced this issue before and provided an example on implementation here:
[Complex example of ListView getItemViewType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277164/complex-example-of-listview-getitemviewtype/15277340#15277340)

Answer (score 0):

From just the code you have exposed here I can see you are creating a Memory Leak.

You hold onto the context (`private final Context context;`) within an Adapter which will be living within that Context. This bi-directionality creates a memory leak where neither can be cleaned up. when this is repeated in other places your application quickly begins to chew through memory which would explain why the application then becomes unresponsive.

You also duplicate your list of items. In the code above you don't seem to have a reason to do this.

```
List<StaffItem> items;
List<StaffItem> itemList;

this.itemList = items1;
items=items1;
```

The last thing to look at is rarely a problem, but you are setting some image resources. Take a look at those image resources and see how big they are. If you have accidentally used very big images and are showing several of them at once from your adapter, this will also be consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see where I duplicate the my list of items. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. I should let you know the the two items are purposeful. One is for a search function. The other is for the full list.

Comment: Also, I already was aware of the image problem, and my images are small.

Comment: I am using a third party library-Parse on this page. I wonder if that could be the issue.

Comment: On this post previously someone mentioned it may be due to my adapter. Let me know if you want any more code snippets.

Comment: What is it parsing? Also is the data loaded from a databse? And is this the first page you go to in your app? Or are you going through a bunch of screens?