# Multiple Row Types in List View

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm fairly new to Android development and I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple row layouts in a list view.

The first row layout is a linear layout with an image view, the next row layout consists of 3 text views and a button (the number of these rows needed will vary according to the number of objects retrieved from an HTTP call), the third layout contains three text views in a linear layout, and the last layout has a map view.

How do I use all of these in a list view?

Comment: Please do a search, this question has been answered many times on StackOverflow and there are tutorials on the web for this.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15277164/4504191